# Laravel DatabaseTransactions do not work with DB Facade

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, transactions, laravel-facade

I have an issue when I run tests using `DatabaseTransactions`. In my Products table, I have all Products where the stock_count = -99.

Here is my code

TestCase.php (all the tests extend this class)

```php
use DatabaseTransactions;

protected $connectionsToTransact = ["mysql"];

public function setUp()
{
   parent::setUp();
   MimProduct::query()->update(['stock_count'=>100]);
   ...
}
```

Then in one of my test, I dd the same query, one using DB Facade the other one using the actual model.

```php
 dd(DB::table("mim.products")->first(),MimProduct::all()->first());
```

and the output is

[image]

My conclusions so far are:

- Using the DB facade doesn’t work with the DB Transaction trait; it cannot use the “in-memory” transactions, and so it will work off the “live” DB.
- Whereas a model has access to memory.

Am I correct or there is a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: What's the default connection for your tests?

Comment: The default connection is mysql

Comment: Your model uses the `mim` connection which is missing from `$connectionsToTransact`. `DB::table("mim.products")` uses the default `mysql` connection.

Comment: I tried as well to put both of the connections in $connectionsToTransact but it did not work, at the end I got rid of "mim" connection and use only the "mysql" and everything worked, it's not a proper solution but better than nothing. Thanks tho]